# Pool.map memory leak when called inside a for loop, inside a class method

Tags: python, memory-leaks, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing pool.map inside a for loop, inside a class method in order to call a global function that instantiates another class and calls its method.

The problem is the memory leak. So each time I run the program, I lose some RAM until I get a MemoryError. Any thoughts on why the leak arises? Thanks!

Also, I am not married to multiprocessing, so if you think another library might work better here, please let me know.

Here's the simplified program:

UPDATE: I am running Linux (openSUSE Leap 15.1)

UPDATE 2: I rewrote it with joblib's `Parallel, delayed` and it seems to work better know. With `joblib`, RAM usage also grows significantly on the first run (compared to a single core run). But after the first run it seems to stay constant, regardless of how many times I run the program. Maybe that sheds light on things?

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from functools import partial

def func(x, my_var, kwargs):
   return MyOtherClass(x, my_var=my_var, **kwargs).some_method()

class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, my_var, my_list, my_list2):
       self.my_var = my_var
       self.my_list = my_list
       self.my_list2 = my_list2
       self.result = []

   def do_parallel_work(self):
       with Pool() as p:
           for kwargs in my_list:
               self.result.extend(list(p.map(partial(
                   func,
                   my_var=self.myvar,
                   kwargs=kwargs
               ), my_list2)))
       return self

class MyOtherClass:
    def __init__(self, x, my_var, **kwargs):
        self.x = x
        self.my_var = my_var
        self.kwarg1 = kwarg1
        self.kwarg2 = kwarg2
        # etc.

    def some_method():
        # do stuff with self
        return self

my_class = MyClass(my_var, my_list, my_list2).do_parallel_work()
```

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @MichaelButscher linux (openSUSE Leap 15)

Comment: Your example would be better if it would compile.  For example, there is a missing parenthesis in the self.result.extend statement.

Comment: @TimBoddy Sorry about that. Good call. Parenthesis added.

Comment: Have you verified that it is runnable in the current form?

Comment: @TimBoddy Sorry, I haven't.